# Locating or downloading tools.jar file Mac

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to host a jsp file with Tomcat and the YouTube videos show them copying the tools.jar file but I can't seem to find it. I downloaded the JDK 17 but no tools came with it. Is the tools named something else on Macs?

Comment: Your video is probably outdated. The current Tomcat version and its JSP implementation (called Jasper) use the Eclipse JDT compiler instead of `tools.jar`. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

`tools.jar` ceased being a thing with JDK9. The tutorial you're reading is a decade out of date. JSPs as a technology are severely outdated as well, you may want to follow some more modern java web framework tutorial instead. JSPs mix HTML and java code and the concept of mixing different codebases to such a degree is something that even PHP (that made the model 'famous') has moved away from.

Modern style either involved static HTML that makes javascript-based requests to the server using a standard API (usually JSON based), obviating the need for JSP or any other templating engine, *or* a much simpler template engine, such as freemarker, velocity, moustache, handlebar, or thymeleaf.

If you insist on contiuning with your tutorial, download a JDK8. [The Adoptium project](https://adoptium.net) still makes builds, as do a few other parties.